# Fit a custom function in python

Tags: python, function, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit my data with the following function:

[image]

The data that I'm using is the following:

```
X1: 
0        1.0
1      101.0
2      201.0
3      301.0
4      401.0
5      501.0
6      601.0
7      701.0
8      801.0
9      901.0
10    1001.0
11    1101.0
12    1201.0
13    1301.0
14    1401.0
15    1501.0
16    1601.0
17    1701.0
18    1801.0
19    1901.0

Y1: 
0     0.121159
1     0.195525
2     0.167305
3     0.125499
4     0.094138
5     0.071610
6     0.053848
7     0.039890
8     0.031099
9     0.023976
10    0.018271
11    0.013807
12    0.010596
13    0.008033
14    0.006710
15    0.005222
16    0.004299
17    0.003376
18    0.002976
19    0.002659
```

My code to call the function looks as follows:

```
def logN(X1, mu, SD1):

return  A/X1 * np.exp(-0.5 * (np.log(X1/mu)**2/np.log(SD1)**2))
        params, pcov = curve_fit(logN, X1,Y1) print (params)


plt.plot(X1, Y1, "o") 
plt.plot(X1, logN(X1 ,params[0], params[1]))  
plt.show()
```

The result of this function shows parameters equal to 1 and I got the following warning:

```
minpack.py:829: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
```

category=OptimizeWarning)

[image]

I'm wondering if I'm calling properly the function of the syntax of my function is wrong. Some ideas?

Comment: ....starting values! Also be aware that while in the limit of x -> 0 the function value is zero, here you are producing a division by zero error.

Comment: I am investigating your problem and I have few questions. It seems you are adjusting a lognormal distribution but your data are not exactly suited for. How confident are you with first (x=1) and last points (x>1600)? Do you have uncertainties on y measurements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Observations

You are facing multiple challenges:

- Stated as you did, your problem is a non linear regression (in term of coefficients) which can be solved using non linear algorithm such as [Levenberg Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) (implemented in `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`)
- You are not considering the `A` coefficient in optimization process but it is explicitly stated in your function (thus it takes a global value that is not detailed in your post) and this `A` coefficient is related to `sigma` as the former incorporate the later.
- Some of your data does not suit a log normal distribution (point at `x=1` seems suspect) and there is no estimation of `y` uncertainty. This may prevent proper convergence when performing parameters optimization and then algorithm fails to compute the covariance matrix.

Improvement proposal:

- It is possible to rewrite your problem into a classical OLS involving a second order polynomial. Then we do not have to rely on NLLS algorithms. Just apply the [log-log transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot) to your relation to confirm it is bearable and get parameters conversion formula. Always prefer OLS before NLLS if available.
- Remove or penalize (weights) suspect points, ideally using an objective criterion.
- Adapt your model function (not considered here).

### MCVE

Based on data you provided:

```
import io
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = io.StringIO("""id;x;y;sy
0;1.0;0.121159;1
1;101.0;0.195525;1
2;201.0;0.167305;1
3;301.0;0.125499;1
4;401.0;0.094138;1
5;501.0;0.071610;1
6;601.0;0.053848;1
7;701.0;0.039890;1
8;801.0;0.031099;1
9;901.0;0.023976;1
10;1001.0;0.018271;1
11;1101.0;0.013807;1
12;1201.0;0.010596;1
13;1301.0;0.008033;1
14;1401.0;0.006710;1
15;1501.0;0.005222;1
16;1601.0;0.004299;1
17;1701.0;0.003376;1
18;1801.0;0.002976;1
19;1901.0;0.002659;1
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";", index_col="id")
```

Rewriting your model function to:

```
def func(x, A, mu, sigma):
    return (A/x)*np.exp(-((np.log(x/mu)/np.log(sigma))**2)/2)
```

### Modified signature

Then we can naively fit the function by providing data and smart enough initial condition to the optimization algorithm:

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, df.x, df.y, sigma=df.sy,
                                p0=(50, 100, 0.1), method="lm")
```

But the result is not very satisfactory (unweighted):

[image]

And prone to variation because of suspect points (penalizing `x=1` with `w=100`):

[image]

Thus having uncertainty on `y` measurements could help to adjust the fit.

Anyway as the problem can be linearized we should rely on this property, weights can be used in OLS as well.

### Linearization

You can perform OLS with [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) if you wish. I will use the `sklearn` framework which is very handy:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
```

Lets remove the first suspect point:

```
df = df.loc[1:,:]
```

Then, we adapt inputs and perform log-log transformation:

```
X = np.log(df.x.values).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.log(df.y)
```

We create the OLS pipeline for a second order polynomial:

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)
linreg = LinearRegression()
model = make_pipeline(poly, linreg)
```

And finally we adjust the model to data:

```
model.fit(X, y)
model.score(X, y) # 0.9982242621455882
```

It leads to:

[image]

Which seems a reasonable adjustment for a quadratic. Then it is just about converting back coefficients into your desired quantities.

Comment: What an elegant solution. I will look at my data twice the next time. Thanks

Comment: @JonathanPacheco, you are welcome, I liked to investigate it.